# Merge two data tables together using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two tables. One has results, the other the red, amber or green that corresponds to the result. Due to the way the data is stored in the database and pivoting, I can't put the query together. So I was thinking of loading both tables and merging them on document ready.

Can anyone explain how to do this? Is jQuery the way to go since I can't manipulate the SQL query? The 'combined' table is the final table I want to show.

```
<table id="results">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="">89.87%</span></td>
    <td><span class="">12.87%</span></td>
    <td><span class="">75.87%</span></td>
  </tr>    
</table>

<table id="rag">
  <tr>
    <td>green</td>
    <td>red</td>
    <td>amber</td>
  </tr>    
</table>

<table id="combined">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="green">89.87%</span></td>
    <td><span class="red">12.87%</span></td>
    <td><span class="amber">75.87%</span></td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: based on your query results, use JS or Jquery to add class to the span element based upon what value you have using if-else statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery merge those table:

```js
var colorArray = [];
$('#rag tr td').each(function(index) {
  colorArray[index] = $(this).text();
});

$('#results tr td').each(function(index) {
  $(this).addClass(colorArray[index]);
});
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="results">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="">89.87%</span></td>
    <td><span class="">12.87%</span></td>
    <td><span class="">75.87%</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="rag">
  <tr>
    <td>green</td>
    <td>red</td>
    <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="combined">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="green">89.87%</span></td>
    <td><span class="red">12.87%</span></td>
    <td><span class="blue">75.87%</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```